# Scanning an array in R

Tags: r, vector

I use R and I have a long numeric vector. I would like to look for all the maximal continuous subranges in this vector, where all values are lower then some threshold.

For example, if the given vector is

`5 5 6 6 7 5 4 4 4 3 2 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 2 3 4 4`

and my threshold is 4 (i.e., `=<3`), then the values that meet this condition are marked with x:

`0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 x x x x x x x 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 x x x x 0 0`

I would also like to return something like `(10,16), (24,27)`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the ranges you can use `rle`

First create the encoding

```
x <- c(5,5,6,6,7,5,4,4,4,3,2,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,2,3,4,4)
enc <- rle(x <= 3)

enc.endidx <- cumsum(enc$lengths) #ending indices
enc.startidx <- c(0, enc.endidx[1:(length(enc.endidx)-1)]) + 1 # starting indices

data.frame(startidx=enc.startidx[enc$values], endidx=enc.endidx[enc$values])
```

That should give you

```
  startidx endidx
1       10     16
2       24     27
```

Comment: If you really want a list of the ranges, you could split the data frame out by rows i.e. If d is the dataframe at the end, you want list(d[1,], d[2,])

It might be a better idea to leave it as a data frame. When you need to use the ranges you can use the apply function along the rows of this data frame.

Comment: Just a comment - `rle()` itself is implemented in terms of `which()`, and seems to copy the input vector several times.  Presumably it could be made quite a bit more efficient if done with a loop or in native code.  I have no empirics to back that up though.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your first question is pretty straight forward:

```
x <- c(5,5,6,6,7,5,4,4,4,3,2,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,2,3,4,4)
y <- x<=3

y
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[13]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[25]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

as.numeric(y)
[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
```

to get the indices as you want them is more difficult.
You can try `which` as proposed by whatnick.
Another possibility is to use `match`. It returns the first element that matches. So `match(1,y)` would return 10. `match(0,y[10:length(y)]) - 1` would return 16. If you can put this into a `while`-loop you could get the indices as you like.

Comment: He means that he will need to locate transtion boundaries. With your example it will be "transitions<-which(diff(1-as.numeric(y))!=0)"

Comment: @whatnick. I finnaly got it, thanks to your comment. and sorry for mixing < and >. I changed it now. Still too early...

Answer (score 0):

The operator you need is "which". The syntax will be indices<-which(vector<=3). This will give you a list of indices where the value meets the condition. To isolate transitions you may use a diffrential of the indices. Where the differential exceeds 1 you have a transition boundary.

Comment: This is exactly my question. given a boolean vector, how do I convert it to a set of `true` ranges?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do this too and this is what I'm using:

```
ranges <- function(b){ # b must be boolean
    b <- c(FALSE,b,FALSE)
    d <- b[-1]-b[-length(b)]
    return(data.frame(start=which(d==1),end=which(d==-1)-1))
}
```

In your example

```
x <- c(5,5,6,6,7,5,4,4,4,3,2,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,5,4,3,2,2,3,4,4)
ranges(x<=3)
```

produces

```
  start end
1    10  16
2    24  27
```